# Regex (repeating group) does not seem to work

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match tag and possible attributes of xml tag.

Here you can find example:
https://regex101.com/r/mZYvGU/1/

```
^([\S]+)(?:\s*([\S]+)="([^"]+)")*
```

test string:

> `tag att1="1" att2="2"`

The problem is - it is always catching last attribute only.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please use a proper XML parser instead of trying to use regular expressions. If you really want to use regular expressions, you will have to catch all matches and likely you will have to parse out the separate attributes after matching the whole attribute string.

Comment: It is *capturing* the last group because that's how captures work. During matching it captures the first, then the second; but when it's done, the capture groups will all be populated with the final captured value. I can only concur that you want a proper XML parser for this.

Comment: Since it's for embedded device I can't use large libraries. Any advise how to fix the regex itself?

Comment: You can try with [flag `y` *sticky*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) to chain matches, if this is of any help. [See your updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZYvGU/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow my example:

```js
let s = `tag att1="1" att2="2" att3="34"`;
let regex = /(.*?)(?<=\s)(\w+)="(\w+)"/ig;
let result = [];
s.replace(regex, function(match,tag,att_name,att_value){
    if(tag.trim()!==''){
        result.push(tag.trim());
        result.push(att_name); //att1
        result.push(att_value); //1
    }else{
        result.push(att_name); //att2 and att3
        result.push(att_value); //2 and 34
    };
});
console.log(result);
```